# sax parser getting nex value for empty tag

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

Im trying to get the values of an xm with sax parser, and when a tag its empty, like  the parser instead of skip that tag save the value of the next tag, here its my parser:

```
public class HandlerRegistrarActa extends DefaultHandler {


    private RegistrarActaBeanReq acta = null;
    private List<Infracciones> infracciones = null;
    private Infracciones infraccion= null;

    public RegistrarActaBeanReq getActa() {
        return acta;
    }

    boolean bid_Acta = false;
    boolean bNro_Acta = false;
    boolean bLetra_Serie = false;
    boolean bInfraccion_Lugar = false;
    boolean bInfraccion_Numero = false;
    boolean bInfraccion_KmAltura = false;
    boolean bInfraccion_Referencia = false;
    boolean bInfraccion_Fec_Hora_Labrada = false;
    boolean bFec_Vencimiento = false;
    boolean bRetiene_Licencia = false;
    boolean bRetene_Vehiculo = false;
    boolean bTipoVehiculo = false;
    boolean bTipoPatente = false;
    boolean bConduccionPeligrosa = false;
    boolean bDominio = false;
    boolean bMarca = false;
    boolean bColor = false;
    boolean bSinTitular = false;
    boolean bTipo_Dni_Propietario = false;
    boolean bDni_propietario = false;
    boolean bNombre_Propietario = false;
    boolean bApellido_Propietario = false;
    boolean bRazon_Social_Propietario = false;
    boolean bCalle_propietario = false;


        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("id_Acta")) {
                bid_Acta = true;
                acta = new RegistrarActaBeanReq();
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Nro_Acta")) {
                bNro_Acta = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Letra_Serie")) {
                bLetra_Serie = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Infraccion_Lugar")) {
                bInfraccion_Lugar = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Infraccion_Numero_Ruta")) {
                bInfraccion_Numero = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Infraccion_KmAltura")) {
                bInfraccion_KmAltura = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Infraccion_Referencia")) {
                bInfraccion_Referencia = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Fec_Hora_Labrada")) {
                bInfraccion_Fec_Hora_Labrada = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Fec_Vencimiento")) {
                bFec_Vencimiento = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Retiene_Licencia")) {
                bRetiene_Licencia = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Retiene_Vehiculo")) {
                bRetene_Vehiculo = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TipoVehiculo")) {
                bTipoVehiculo = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TipoPatente")) {
                bTipoPatente = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ConduccionPeligrosa")) {
                bConduccionPeligrosa = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Dominio")) {
                bDominio= true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Marca")) {
                bMarca = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Color")) {
                bColor = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SinTitular")) {
                bSinTitular = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tipo_Dni_Propietario")) {
                bTipo_Dni_Propietario = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Dni_propietario")) {
                bDni_propietario = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Nombre_Propietario")) {
                bNombre_Propietario = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Apellido_Propietario")) {
                bApellido_Propietario = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Razon_Social_Propietario")) {
                bRazon_Social_Propietario = true;
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Calle_propietario")) {
                bCalle_propietario = true;
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            if (bid_Acta) {
                acta.setId_Acta(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bid_Acta = false;
            } else if (bNro_Acta) {
                acta.setNro_Acta(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bNro_Acta = false;
            } else if (bLetra_Serie) {
                acta.setLetra_Serie(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bLetra_Serie = false;
            } else if (bInfraccion_Lugar) {
                acta.setInfraccion_Lugar(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bInfraccion_Lugar = false;
            } else if (bInfraccion_Numero) {
                acta.setInfraccion_Numero_Ruta(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bInfraccion_Numero = false;
            } else if (bInfraccion_KmAltura) {
                acta.setInfraccion_KmAltura(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bInfraccion_KmAltura = false;
            }else if (bInfraccion_Referencia) {
                acta.setInfraccion_Referencia(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bInfraccion_Referencia = false;
            } else if (bInfraccion_Fec_Hora_Labrada) {
                acta.setFec_Hora_Labrada(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bInfraccion_Fec_Hora_Labrada = false;
            } else if (bFec_Vencimiento) {
                acta.setFec_Vencimiento(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bFec_Vencimiento = false;
            } else if (bRetiene_Licencia) {
                acta.setRetiene_Licencia(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bRetiene_Licencia = false;
            } else if (bRetene_Vehiculo) {
                acta.setRetene_vehiculo(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bRetene_Vehiculo = false;
            }else if (bTipoVehiculo) {
                acta.setTipo_Vehiculo(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bTipoVehiculo = false;
            } else if (bTipoPatente) {
                acta.setTipo_Patente(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bTipoPatente = false;
            } else if (bConduccionPeligrosa) {
                acta.setConduccion_Peligrosa(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bConduccionPeligrosa = false;
            } else if (bDominio) {
                acta.setDominio(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bDominio = false;
            } else if (bMarca) {
                acta.setMarca(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bMarca = false;
            }else if (bColor) {
                acta.setColor(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bColor = false;
            } else if (bSinTitular) {
                acta.setSinTitular(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bSinTitular = false;
            } else if (bTipo_Dni_Propietario) {
                acta.setTipo_Dni_Propietartio(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bTipo_Dni_Propietario = false;
            } else if (bDni_propietario) {
                acta.setDni_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bDni_propietario = false;
            } else if (bNombre_Propietario) {
                acta.setNombre_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bNombre_Propietario = false;
            }else if (bApellido_Propietario) {
                acta.setApellido_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bApellido_Propietario = false;
            } else if (bRazon_Social_Propietario) {
                acta.setRazon_Social_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bRazon_Social_Propietario = false;
            } else if (bCalle_propietario) {
                acta.setCalle_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
                bCalle_propietario = false;
            } 
        }
    }
```

the xml im trying to get the values its:

```
<SDTActaCaminera xmlns='VialMza'><Acta>
<Id_Acta>1</Id_Acta>
<Nro_Acta>K0000000001</Nro_Acta>
<Letra_Serie>989</Letra_Serie>
<Infraccion_Lugar>RUTA NACIONAL</Infraccion_Lugar>
<Infraccion_Numero_Ruta>142</Infraccion_Numero_Ruta>
<Infraccion_KmAltura>10</Infraccion_KmAltura>
<Infraccion_Referencia>Aaa</Infraccion_Referencia>
<Fec_Hora_Labrada>20/02/2018 11:55:30</Fec_Hora_Labrada>
<Fec_Vencimiento>07/03/2018</Fec_Vencimiento>
<Retiene_Licencia>N</Retiene_Licencia>
<Retiene_Vehiculo>S</Retiene_Vehiculo>
<TipoVehiculo>AUTOMOVIL</TipoVehiculo>
<TipoPatente>AGF310</TipoPatente>
<ConduccionPeligrosa>S</ConduccionPeligrosa>
<Dominio>AGF310</Dominio>
<Marca>FIAT</Marca>
<Color>ROJO</Color>
<SinTitular>N</SinTitular>
<Tipo_Dni_Propietario>DNI</Tipo_Dni_Propietario>
<Dni_Propietario>31156986</Dni_Propietario>
<Nombre_Propietario>ANDRES</Nombre_Propietario>
<Apellido_Propietario>MARCOS</Apellido_Propietario>
<Razon_Social_Propietario></Razon_Social_Propietario>
<Calle_Propietario>AAA</Calle_Propietario>
</Acta>
</SDTActaCaminera>
```

as you can see tag razon_social_propietario its empty and instead of skip that tag it save the next tag value(in this case AAA)

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve] - there's no need for us to wade through nearly 500 lines of code. But when you reduce it, it would be very helpful if you'd make it *complete* as well - make it so we can just copy, compile, and run, with a main method etc.

Comment: I just reduce the code untill the tag im having the problem

Comment: It's still nearly 200 lines of code, and incomplete. You should reduce it to *just* what's required to reproduce the problem, including reducing the XML file as far as possible too.

Comment: (Fundamentally your approach of having all those booleans seems problematic to me though. Why not just keep the last-encountered element name?)

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest adding diagnostics logging when each of the methods is being called and with what values.

Comment: If you use booleans like this, unset them in the end tag, not on the next text. Because there will be no text if the tag is empty.

Comment: thanks a lot @JohannesKuhn i putted the value in false on tags end and its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be broken down to:

```
public class HandlerRegistrarActa extends DefaultHandler {
    private RegistrarActaBeanReq acta = null;
    private boolean bRazon_Social_Propietario = false;
    private boolean bCalle_propietario = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("id_Acta")) {
            bid_Acta = true;
            acta = new RegistrarActaBeanReq();
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Razon_Social_Propietario")) {
            bRazon_Social_Propietario = true;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Calle_propietario")) {
            bCalle_propietario = true;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (bRazon_Social_Propietario) {
            acta.setRazon_Social_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
            bRazon_Social_Propietario = false;
        } else if (bCalle_propietario) {
            acta.setCalle_Propietario(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
            bCalle_propietario = false;
        } 
    }
}
```

with the following XML:

```
<SDTActaCaminera xmlns='VialMza'>
    <Acta>
         <Razon_Social_Propietario></Razon_Social_Propietario>
         <Calle_Propietario>AAA</Calle_Propietario>
    </Acta>
</SDTActaCaminera>
```

This is your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (or short MCVE).

So, what happens if there is an empty tag?
The `characters` method is not called for that element.
So `bRazon_Social_Propietario` will stay `true`.
And the next time `characters` is called, it will use that as value for `Razon_Social_Propietario`.
But it is not longer in that tag, but in the next tag.

To fix that, you have to unset the booleans in `endElement`:

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Razon_Social_Propietario")) {
        bRazon_Social_Propietario = false;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Calle_propietario")) {
        bCalle_propietario = false;
    }
}
```

I leave it to you to implement this for all properties.

Answer (score 1):

Of course your code is doing that.

When you hit a empty tag, `startElement` and `endElement` is called, but `characters` is not, so when the next element hits, you end up with **two** flags set.

I would suggest you get rid of all the flags, and remember the active tag name instead, then clear that name in `endElement`. You then do the multi-way name check in `characters` and assign as necessary. Will greatly simplify your code too.

```
private RegistrarActaBeanReq acta = new RegistrarActaBeanReq();
private String activeName;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    activeName = qName;
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    activeName = null;
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (activeName == null)
        return;
    if (activeName.equalsIgnoreCase("id_Acta"))
        acta.setId_Acta(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
    else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Nro_Acta"))
        acta.setNro_Acta(new String(ch, start, length).trim());
    else if ...
        ...
}
```

I would however suggest you use a StAX parser instead. Much easier to use.